# Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'login'

Tags: angular

my page http: // localhost:4200 load correctly, but when i want to go to the link http: // localhost: 4200 /login it return to the link http: // localhost: 4200 and show error.

localhost: 4200 /login it return to the link http: // localhost: 4200 and show error.

**routing-module.module.ts**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { RouterModule , Routes} from '@angular/router';
import { LoginComponent } from './components/login/login.component';
import { TaskManagerComponent } from './components/task-manager/task-manager.component';


const routes:Routes=[
   { path : 'login',component:LoginComponent },
   { path : 'task' ,component:TaskManagerComponent }
];

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    LoginComponent

  ],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    RouterModule.forRoot(routes),
    RoutingModuleModule
  ],
  exports:[RouterModule]
})
export class RoutingModuleModule { }
```

**app.module.ts**

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule , Routes} from '@angular/router';


import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { HeaderComponent } from './components/header/header.component';
import { FooterComponent } from './components/footer/footer.component';
import { TaskManagerComponent } from './components/task-manager/task-manager.component';
import { TaskFormComponent } from './components/task-manager/task-form/task-form.component';
import { TaskListComponent } from './components/task-manager/task-list/task-list.component';
import { TaskDetailComponent } from './components/task-manager/task-detail/task-detail.component';
import { TaskItemComponent } from './components/task-manager/task-list/task-item/task-item.component';

const appRoute:Routes = [
  {path:'' ,component:TaskManagerComponent}

]

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    HeaderComponent,
    FooterComponent,
    TaskManagerComponent,
    TaskFormComponent,
    TaskListComponent,
    TaskDetailComponent,
    TaskItemComponent,
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
       RouterModule.forRoot(appRoute)

  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

**app.component.html**

```
 <div class="row">
    <div class="col">
        <app-header></app-header>
    </div>
  </div>
  <hr>
  <div class="row mt-5 mb-5">
    <div class="col mx-auto">
      <router-outlet></router-outlet>
    </div>
  </div>
  <hr>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col">
      <app-footer></app-footer>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because you are declaring routes in the `app.module.ts` as well as `routing-module.module.ts`. Declare all your routes in the routing module instead. You can use `@angular/cli` to generate your routing module so it's created with a better name. If you create it using `cli` commands, set the name as `routing` as Angular will already add `module` for you. explicity adding `module` to your name will give you the redudant `Module` word in your class name (`RoutingModuleModule`).

Remove the routes created in your `app.module.ts` and import `RoutingModule` (or `RoutingModuleModule` in your case)

```
imports: [
  BrowserModule,
  RoutingModuleModule
]
```

Move the route from your `app.module.ts` to your `routing.module.ts`

```
const routes: Routes = [
   { path: '' , redirectTo: '/task', pathMatch: 'full' }
   { path: 'login', component: LoginComponent },
   { path: 'task' , component: TaskManagerComponent }
];
```