# Adding Google authentication to ASP.NET with Angular Visual Studio template

Tags: c#, asp.net, angular, authentication

I have a project that I created with the ASP.NET with Angular Visual Studio template with the individual accounts authentication type.

I then added Google authentication by following the steps outlined here.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/social/google-logins?view=aspnetcore-6.0

However, when I try and register, I get a error in the console stating

> Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'signin-google'.

I tried following the exact same steps but with asp.net core web app using razor pages instead of angular, and it works properly. Is there something that I am missing with Angular?

Thanks for any suggestions

Comment: Did you see this? Always good to show your research. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57269386/error-cannot-match-any-routes-url-segment-login

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'login'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57269386/error-cannot-match-any-routes-url-segment-login)

Comment: @JeremyThompson I managed to fix my problem. Angular was taking over the routing, when asp.net Identity should have been taking over. I fixed it, by changing the redirect URL for google by adding this line "googleOptions.CallbackPath = new PathString("/Identity/signin-google");" to my Program.cs file.

Comment: @PhadonPhipat put it as an answer. It's OK to answer your own questions.

Answer (score 3):

I managed to fix my problem. Angular was taking over the routing, when asp.net Identity should have been taking over. I fixed it, by changing the redirect URL for google by adding this line "googleOptions.CallbackPath = new PathString("/Identity/signin-google");" to my Program.cs file.

Answer (score 2):

You need to tell angular to exclude that route and forward it to the backend, by adding it in `proxy.conf.js`:

```js
const PROXY_CONFIG = [
  {
    context: [
      "/weatherforecast",
      "/_configuration",
      "/.well-known",
      "/Identity",
      "/connect",
      "/ApplyDatabaseMigrations",
      "/_framework",
      "/signin-google", //           <---- Right here
    ],
    target: target,
    secure: false,
    headers: {
      Connection: 'Keep-Alive'
    }
  }
]
```

NOTE: The full path in the default .NET Angular template is `ClientApp\proxy.conf.js`